# Bootstrap "collpase in" not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to toggle the div element. I am using the following code, its working for its default behavior i.e. to hide the toggled content in the beginning.

I want to show the toggled content at the beginning and so using "collapse in" bootstrap class as suggested on their site. But still its giving its default behavior to hide the content at the beginning.

**Code snippet**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">+ Datum</button>
<div id="demo" class="collapse in">
    <div>
        <label>Attributes (Element) </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** All the necessary files for working of bootstrap have been added i.e. bootstrap and jquery file.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Working for me http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/1717/ , might be something else is causing problem , if possible create a fiddle !!

Comment: maybe there's something in your javascript code that cause this bug

Comment: Hi @zan can you tell me what versions of bootstrap and jquery files are you using ?

Comment: @AjinkyaWani V3

Answer (score 0):

Your Code Working Fine .some How `bootstrap.min.js` , & css Missing .

**Check Live Demo** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/8cdaa274/)

**Snippet Example**

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">+ Datum</button>
<div id="demo" class="collapse in">
    <div>
        <label>Attributes (Element) </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so. after  issue are there then insert your question full code .other wise code are worked .

Comment: were not able to inset full code since its too large in size and divided in multiple files. I have included bootstrap and jquery files to some other common place. anyways thanks for your concern.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the following things.

> 1. You have included bootstrap js and css and jQuery
> 2. As well as the jQuery version is latest.

I have attached a sample snippet. This seems to be working perfect for me.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">+ Datum</button>
<div id="demo" class="collapse in">
    <div>
        <label>Attributes (Element) </label>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your concern and comments, those were helpful. Issue got resolved, in our project solution we were having some bootstrap overridden classes, so "collapse in" class was conflicting with one of those overridden classes.

cheers..